# Kotlin infers JOOQ methods wrong

Tags: kotlin, jooq

Given a system using Kotlin version 1.3.61 and JOOQ version 3.13.1, a method like this builds an `union` query normally:

```
    val selectCommonPart = coalesce(sum(field(name("amount"), Long::class.java)), ZERO)
            .`as`(field(name("totalAmount")))
    var whereCommonPart: Condition = trueCondition().and(field(name("Id")).eq(Id)) // Id comes as a parameter

    var query = dsl.selectQuery()
    query.addSelect(selectCommonPart)
    query.addFrom(table("${tableName(startDate)}")) // `startDate` is a `LocalDate`, `tableName()` generates the table name as String
    query.addConditions(whereCommonPart)

    // `endDate` is also a `LocalDate`, can be either equal to `startDate` or after
    if (endDate.isAfter(startDate)) {
        for (date in Stream.iterate(startDate.plusDays(1), { d: LocalDate -> d.plusDays(1) })
                .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())) {

            val unionQuery = dsl.selectQuery()
            unionQuery.addSelect(selectCommonPart)
            unionQuery.addFrom(table("public.${tableName(date)}"))
            unionQuery.addConditions(whereCommonPart)

            // Here `union` is inferred correctly
            query.union(dsl.select(selectCommonPart)
                    .from("public.public.${tableName(date)}")
                    .where(whereCommonPart))
        }
    }
```

However, if I isolate the `dsl.select(...)` part in a method like:

```
private fun buildSelect(selectCommonPart: Field<*>, whereCommonPart: Condition, date: LocalDate): Select<*> {
    var query = dsl.selectQuery()
    query.addSelect(selectCommonPart)
    query.addFrom(table("public.${tableName(date)}"))
    query.addConditions(whereCommonPart)
    return query
}
```

And modify the loop to use:

```
    // Remove this part
    /* var query = dsl.selectQuery()
    query.addSelect(selectCommonPart)
    query.addFrom(table("${tableName(startDate)}")) // `startDate` is a `LocalDate`, `tableName()` generates the table name as String
    query.addConditions(whereCommonPart) */

    // Add this part
    var query = buildSelect(selectCommonPart, whereCommonPart, startDate)

    if (endDate.isAfter(startDate)) {
        for (date in Stream.iterate(startDate.plusDays(1), { d: LocalDate -> d.plusDays(1) })
                .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())) {

            // This gives an inference error
            query.union(buildSelect(selectCommonPart, whereCommonPart, date))
        }
    }
```

I have an inference error. Kotlin resolves `union` as this method:

```
/**
 * Returns a set containing all distinct elements from both collections.
 * 
 * The returned set preserves the element iteration order of the original collection.
 * Those elements of the [other] collection that are unique are iterated in the end
 * in the order of the [other] collection.
 * 
 * To get a set containing all elements that are contained in both collections use [intersect].
 */

public infix fun <T> Iterable<T>.union(other: Iterable<T>): Set<T> {
    val set = this.toMutableSet()
    set.addAll(other)
    return set
}
```

I want to use JOOQ's `Select<*>`'s `union` instead:

```
public interface Select<R extends Record> extends ResultQuery<R>, TableLike<R>, FieldLike {

    /**
     * Apply the <code>UNION</code> set operation.
     */
    @Support
    Select<R> union(Select<? extends R> select);
```

What should I do to infer the correct `union` method?

Comment: My Kotlin-fu is not very good, so I can't answer with an explanation about why this would happen, but is it really best practice to infer function return types, rather than providing them explicitly, especially when a complex type system as jOOQ's is involved ([a jOOQ `ResultQuery` extends `Iterable`](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/09/27/a-hidden-jooq-gem-foreach-loop-over-resultquery/))? From what I recall, in Scala, people would usually declare function return types explicitly

Comment: @LukasEder Tried this already, with many different return types. All of them infer to `Iterable` at some point.

Comment: I have copied your code to the my project and don't see the described behavior, Select.union is executed in my case. Do you have the issue in runtime or how do you detect it? Do you try to execute the code and check which one union is executed?

Comment: @MaximPopov My code doesn't even compile because Kotlin resolves the inflection to Kotlin standard library. How did you get to run it?

Comment: I didn't do anything special, just copied your code. See my test example here https://github.com/makcpop/sof-kotlin-jooq . Does it work on your PC?

Comment: @MaximPopov Thanks for sending me your test. I'll update the question with some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to fix your issue.

Method *buildSelect* should returns *Select< Record>*, not *Select< *>*.

My suggestion why it happens:

The Select.union method has the following signature

```
public interface Select<R extends Record> extends ResultQuery<R>, TableLike<R>, FieldLike {
    @Support
    Select<R> union(Select<? extends R> var1);
....
```

As you can see, **var1** should have the same generic( or extended) type as the object on which method was called. In your first implementation, method *dsl.selectQuery()* returns *SelectQuery< Record>* and both are variables *query* and *unionQuery* have the same generic type and the union method is correctly determined.

In the second implementation, *query* and the argument of *query.union(...)* have *Select< *>* type. I guess that the compiler thinks that both variables have different generic(since it is not determined and can be different) and the compiler can't use union from Select, but both variables implement *Iterable* and compiler choose *Iterable.union* since it fits.

Comment: Excellent. Worked with `private fun buildSelect(selectCommonPart: Field<*>, whereCommonPart: Condition, date: LocalDate): SelectQuery<Record> { ... }`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that for `Select`'s `union` the argument's type parameter must be a subtype of the receiver's (`? extends R`); if both are `Select<*>`, it could be e.g. `Select<Int>.union(Select<String>)` which wouldn't type-check. This doesn't happen for `Iterable` because it's covariant.

I think `buildSelect` can be typed more precisely as

```
private fun <T : Record> buildSelect(selectCommonPart: Field<T>, whereCommonPart: Condition, date: LocalDate): Select<T>
```

and then since both calls have the same first argument it should work out.

EDIT: I simply assumed the types of `selectCommonPart` and the returned query had to match, but [they don't](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SelectQuery.html#addSelect(org.jooq.SelectFieldOrAsterisk...)) and `dsl.selectQuery()` returns `Select<Record>`, so the signature in Maxim Popov's answer is the correct one.

Comment: The only problem here is that I'm not passing `Field<Record>` for this particular case: I'm passing `Field<BigDecimal!>!`, what makes Kotlin complain about the data types. For cases that I'm just using `Field<Record>` for `selectCommonPart`, this answer is great!